# Rewrite to other server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting

I have application hosted in tomcat under port 8050; `mydomain:8050`. Now, I want to have friendly url, say `mydomain.com` to be used to access `mydomain:8050` without the client seeing the port number in the URL. Client should always see `mydomain.com` that should be internally resolved to `mydomain:8050`.

I have IIS server running on port 80. I created a site in it just to use rewrite option that can resolve to `mydomain:8050`. It didn't work with the pattern I used

**Pattern:** `((?:[^\/\n]|\/\/)+)(.*)`
**Rewrite URL:** `{R:1}:8050{R:2}`

Then I installed apache http server on port 90. Used redirection in IIS site to redirect the URL to `mydomain:90$S$Q` and then used rewrite in Apache to internally redirect it to `mydomain:8050`. This works when I have a query string in it, like `mydomain.com/queryString`, but doesn't work if I type just `mydomain.com`. I can see it redirecting to `mydomain:90` and stops there without any rewrite rules being executed. This also changes the URL to `mydomain:90` and is visible to client.

My requirement is that when user enters `mydomain.com` it should internally resolve to `mydomain:8050` (with query string if any) without client seeing it. I have IIS running at port 80 and apache running on port 90. How can I achieve this? I am sure this can be handled in rewrite rule of IIS, but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rewriting to another server is basically proxying. What we need is a
>   reverse proxy setup in IIS which basically proxy all your requests
>   from http://example.com to to http://example:8050/(or better
>   http://localhost:8050)

- Make sure you have [ARR](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) module installed on IIS
- Create a reverse proxy rule like this

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://mydomain:8050/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

**Please note that since both Apcahe and IIS are in the same server,you can use localhost:8050 as backend proxy.**

**EDIT:**

Also if you have any redirect coming back from the backend proxy and you do not want to redirect the Location header coming ,You can do that by unchecking "Reverse rewritehost in response headers" in Application Request Routing

- Select the server node in IIS manager
- Go to Application Request routing Cache
- Click on Server proxy Settings
- UnCheck "Reverse rewritehost in response headers"

[image: Reverse rewrite host in response headers]

Comment: I tried this, but I don't see it rewriting to `mydomain:8050`. It gives error when accessing `mydomain.com`

Comment: what error does it give? Do you have ARR installed ,without that it will not work

Comment: Sorry, I missed about ARR. How do I check if it is installed? I am fairly new to IIS.

Comment: I tried to install ARR and it says it is already Installed. So I believe it is already present in there.

Comment: So the issue after rewrite rules is

I access `mydomain.com` and it internally rewrites to `mydomain:8050` that internally redirects to my single sign on server for authentication whose url is `some.sso.com/context/some-string`. However, I see that it redirects to `mydomain.com/context/some-string` that fails with error `404`. I guess `some.sso.com...` is get converted to `mydomain.com/context ...` which is incorrect.

Comment: oh my god. I can't believe it's working. Indeed you are a genius. Thanks a lot for that.